# Cloud Functions puppeteer Error: net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED at http://www.google.com

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

On google Cloud Functions when I try to use puppeteer I get the following error for all sites that I try, an example for google.com:

```
Error: net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED at http://www.google.com
    at navigate (/srv/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:101:37)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:110:27)
    at Page.goto (/srv/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:656:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
    at /srv/index.js:35:20
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

the Cloud Functions code:

```js
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");
    const cors = require("cors")({origin: true});
    const Firestore = require("@google-cloud/firestore");
    const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
    const cheerio = require("cheerio");

    exports.getSiteOne = functions
      .runWith({ memory: "2GB" })
      .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        cors(req, res, async function() {
          try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
              headless: true,
              args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
            });
            const page = await browser.newPage();

            await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3419.0 Safari/537.36');

            await page.goto("http://www.google.com", {
              waitUntil: "networkidle0"
            });

            var html = await page.content();

            res.status(200).json({
              message: "cron added",
              html
            });
          } 
          catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
              error: err
            });
          }
        });
      });
```

puppeteer version "^1.14.0"

NB: when I serve it locally it works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is saying that the DNS lookup fails. I'm assuming you are on the free ["Spark Plan"](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/). That one is not allowing any outgoing traffic:

> Outbound networking: Google services only