# Can't get a signed url after uploading

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

After uploading a file the function gets stuck getting the signed url.

When the file.getSignedUrl() is commented out the function works.

```
fstream.on('finish', function () {
    var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
    // Upload a local file to a new file to be created in your bucket.
    bucket.upload(tempFilePath,{ destination: filePath+fileName} ,function (err, file) {
    if (!err) {
    console.log("Uploaded: " + fileName);
    fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
    return file.getSignedUrl({
        action: 'read',
        expires: '03-17-2500'
        }, function(error, url) {
            if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return callback(new Error('could not get url: ', error))
            }
        console.log("Uploaded url : " + url);
        return callback(null, url)
        })

        //return callback(null, "happy")

        }else{
            console.error("err: " + err);
            return callback(new Error('could not upload'))
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: are you sure the service account you are using to execute the function has the permission "iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob" ? is required when retrieving the signed url.

Comment: Finally got the service accounts working, but now getting this error at        /srv/Index.js:120:51
       at <anonymous>
       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Comment: Could you provide more details on the error?, it seems like your code is actually bigger than what you have shared with us and that error is related to the firebase part. Looking a another SO case [1] I probably found the reason why, the error could be saying that the DNS lookup fails. I'm assuming you are on the free "Spark Plan"  And that one is not allowing any outgoing traffic. [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508640/cloud-functions-puppeteer-error-neterr-name-resolution-failed-at-http-www-g

Comment: Thanks fo all the help but it was just the Google IAM API that wasn't enabled. The error popped up on the console logs

Comment: Hi @youSeeMe, good work finding the solution! Can you answer your question and accept ti? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand signed URL check the [Google Cloud Storage Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

For Cloud Function with Node.js [getSignedUrl](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.5.x/File#getSignedUrl) you can [use as a reference this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/bda5a4dfbef146143dd1e486afe3b6966524cf99/functions/http/index.js#L196).

Prerequisites needed to sign the blob:

1. Google `Identity and Access Management (IAM) API`     [has to be enabled in the project](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en)
2. Service account needs permission: iam.serviceAccounts.{getAccessToken, signBlob}
   [Cloud functions service account (cloudfunctions.serviceAgent) has this permission](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#cloud_functions_service_account)